# Treat an array as circular array when selecting elements - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array on which I loop over. I have another array from which I need to select one by one but it needs to go on circle in case it gets to the end of the array. To make it clear here is some code:

```
$mainArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$size      = count($mainArray);
$circular  = array('A', 'B', 'C');

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
   echo $mainArray[$i] . ' = ' . $circular[$i] . ', ';
}
```

Now above code prints this:

```
1 = A, 2 = B, 3 = C, UNDEFINED INDEX ERROR
```

What I need it to print is this:

```
1 = A, 2 = B, 3 = C, 4 = A, 5 = B, 6 = C, 7 = A, 8 = B, 9 = C, 10 = A
```

Is there a built in function to PHP that turns an array into circular array? I think I need to use modular operator to achieve this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Get the size of the circular array (`$circsize`)and then mod the value `$i` against it and use that as your index:

```
$mainArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
$size      = count($mainArray);
$circular  = array('A', 'B', 'C');
$circsize  = count($circular);

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
   echo $mainArray[$i] . ' = ' . $circular[$i % $circsize] . ', ';
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I like Chris Walsh's but here is an alternate that also works for associative arrays (non-integer indexes). Could probably be shortened:

```
foreach($mainArray as $main) {
    if(($circ = current($circular)) === false) {
        $circ = reset($circular);
    }
    next($circular);
    echo "$main=$circ ";
}
```

If you need this more than once, maybe a function:

```
function circular(&$array) {
    if(($result = current($array)) === false) {
        $result = reset($array);
    }
    next($array);

    return $result;
}
```

Then just use:

```
foreach($mainArray as $main) {
    $circ = circular($circular);
    echo "$main=$circ ";
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the value of an array element is falsey. `circular` will go back to the beginning of the array whenever it reaches that element.

Comment: Thanks.  Edited to check `=== false`.  So array element maybe `false` but oh well.

Comment: This kind of solution works as long as `false` is not a valid element of the array. The solution using modulus works more generally.

Comment: Yes, I noted that.  Works more generally on numerically indexed arrays.  Not at all on associative.

Answer (score 3):

please use remainder for the circular array index:

```
 $i2= $i % count($circular );
 echo $mainArray[$i] . ' = ' . $circular[$i2] . ', ';
```

As an alternate, you can use `foreach` to iterate through arrays and avoid using arithmetic calculations for the index:

```
reset($circular);
foreach($mainArray as $item){
     echo $item . ' = ' . current($circular);
     if(next($circular)===false) reset($circular);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **PHP 5.5** or above, then you could take advantage of php's [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) and its [**yield**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield) keyword:

```
function loopOnArrayFor($array, $limit = 1000)
{
    for ($i = 0 ; $i <= count($array) ; $i++) {
        if ( $i == count($array)) {
            if (--$limit > 0) {
                $i = 0;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        yield $array[$i];
    }
}
```

So this method will loop on the given array for 1000 times unless you pass another value for the `$limit` argument. here is the use case:

```
foreach (loopOnArrayFor(['A','B','C'],5) as $v) {
    echo "$v ,";
}
```

which results in the following output:

```
A ,B ,C ,A ,B ,C ,A ,B ,C ,A ,B ,C ,A ,B ,C ,
```

A little adjustment will give us your expected result:

```
$counter = 1;
foreach (loopOnArrayFor(['A','B','C'],5) as $v) {
    echo $counter++ . ' = ' . $v .', ' ;
}
```

Something like:

```
1 = A, 2 = B, 3 = C, 4 = A, 5 = B, 6 = C, 7 = A, 8 = B, 9 = C, 10 = A, 11 = B, 12 = C, 13 = A, 14 = B, 15 = C,
```

---

P. S. *What you are seeking, can easily lead to memory exhaustion so if you can, find another solution instead of being relied on a (controlled) infinite loop :)*