# PHP circular loop through array from n to n-1 element

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Let's say I have this array:

```
$myArray = array(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
```

And I have a start indicator, `$startpos`, whose possible value can be any value from 0 to myArray's number of elements.

So if `$startpos = 0`, the desired print result would be `a, b, c, d, e, f, g`

if `$startpos = 2`, the desired print result would be `c, d, e, f, g, a, b`

if `$startpos = 5`, the desired print result would be `f, g, a, b, c, d, e`

I've been searching a php built-in or custom function through SO (similar question at [Treat an array as circular array when selecting elements - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141779/treat-an-array-as-circular-array-when-selecting-elements-php)) and having a look to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp but I'm not getting the desired result. Anyone could please give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `array_slice` function  with `array_merge` function as following :

```
$myArray = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');
$startpos = 2;


$output = array_merge(
                 array_slice($myArray,$startpos),
                 array_slice($myArray, 0, $startpos)
                    ); 
var_dump($output);
```

output:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "e"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "f"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "g"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, buddy ;)

Answer (score 2):

[demo](https://eval.in/686739)

```
 <?php
      $myArray = array(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
      $startpos = 3;
      $o = f($myArray, $startpos);
      echo json_encode($o);

      function f($myArray, $startpos)
      {
        $o = array();
        $l = count($myArray);
        array_walk($myArray, function($v, $k) use(&$o, $l, $startpos)
        {
          $o[($k + $l - $startpos) % $l] = $v;
        });
        ksort($o);
        return ($o);
      }
```

or use foreach method. [demo](https://eval.in/686747)

```
<?php
  $myArray = array(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
  $startpos = 3;
  echo json_encode(f($myArray, $startpos));

  function f($myArray, $startpos)
  {
    $o = array();
    $l = count($myArray);
    foreach($myArray as $k => $v)
    {
      $o[($k + $l - $startpos) % $l] = $v;
    }
    ksort($o);
    return $o;
  }
```

outpur:`["d","e","f","g","a","b","c"]`

Comment: @b1919676 my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple logic you can go for the below codepiece:

```
$myArray = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g');
$startpos = <any_position>;
$dummy_startpos = $startpos;  //keeping safe startpos for circular calculation
$initialpos = 0;

//loop to print element from startpos to end
while($dummy_startpos < count($myArray))
{
    echo $myArray[$dummy_startpos] . ' ';
    $dummy_startpos++;
}

//if startpos is not initial position
//start from first and print element till startpos
if($startpos > 0)
{
    while($elementleft < $startpos)
    {
        echo $myArray[$elementleft] . ' ';
        $elementleft++;
    }
}
```

Output :

> $startpos : 3
>
> o/p : d e f g a b c
>
> $startpos : 0
>
> o/p : a b c d e f g